# Podspec dependency is not getting downloaded with vendored framework from URL

Tags: cocoapods

When I am using vendored framework in my podspec and downloading the framework from URL:

```
s.source       = { :http => "https://example.com/MyFramework.xcframework.zip" }
s.vendored_framework = 'MyFramework.xcframework'
```

and have below the line:

```
s.dependency 'MyPublicPod', '= 0.1.0'
```

the dependency somehow is not being downloaded.
But if I separately install `pod 'MyPublicPod'` it gets downloaded.
What might be the issue? Cannot I download dependency when using vendored framework from URL?

On `pod install` it ONLY downloads `MyFramework.xcframework` but my dependency is not getting downloaded.